# How to call CriteriaBuilder.lessThan with parameter of Object type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In the deprecated Criteria API I can do something like this:

```
Object value = myFunc(); //this function returns numeric value based on some criteria
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("column", value));
```

The important functionality for me is to not know the type at compile time, this is determined in runtime. In the new CriteriaQuery API when I try to call the below code it gives me an error.

```
Object value = myFunc(); //this function returns numeric value based on some criteria
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
criteriaQuery.where(builder.lessThan(root.get("column"), value));
```

Cannot resolve method 'lessThanOrEqualTo(javax.persistence.criteria.Path, java.lang.Object)'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So just cast the `value` to `Comparable` as the API expects it.

Comment: Won't that cause any type conversion loss?

Comment: No. The worst you could get is a `ClassCastException`, but you would have most probably gotten that before as well. A cast is no conversion, except when you cast a wider primitive to a smaller one. But you only cast an object of one static type to another. The runtime type won't change due to that.

Comment: I was really stuck on this problem and searched almost everywhere I could've thought about and finally reached here. Thanks! I guess I should learn more about the `Comparable` interface. I haven't heard about it before.